# Is it possible to post directly from an HTML form to a php object method?

Tags: php, html

Thought I saw mention of this somewhere before, but can not find it now.

What I am wanting to do is include a class from another file, then process everything on the main page through an object set.

Something like:

```
<?php 
   $myObject = new Object;
?>
```

Then make a call directly to a method of the object.

```
<form action=<?php $myObject->formPost(); ?> method="post"> //something like this
```

What I am wondering is, is there a way to do this without having to post to a file?

Comment: No such way that I know of, but you can post the form to the same page and read it with PHP. Or you can use Ajax.

Comment: Have you explored AJAX yet? ->http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: Might have to look into AJAX, haven't dug into it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. You will really have to process the form yourself. What you can do is the following (note, I'm not sure if this is secure at all, but I doubt it is):

```
<?php
$object = new MyObject();
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
    $object->$k = $v;
}
```

Comment: Kinda what I figured, was wanting to find a way to keep everything encapsulated for a data processing class, and reduce the number of transactions.